# constructor function's object literal returns toString() method but no other method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, oop, call

I'm very confused with JavaScript methods defined in objects and the `this` keyword.

In the below example, the `toString()` method is invoked when `Mammal` object instantiated:

```
function Mammal(name){ 
  this.name=name;
  this.toString = function(){
    return '[Mammal "'+this.name+'"]';
  }
}

var someAnimal = new Mammal('Mr. Biggles');
alert('someAnimal is '+someAnimal);
```

Despite the fact that the `toString()` method is not invoked on the object `someAnimal` like this:

```
alert('someAnimal is '+someAnimal.toString());
```

It still returns `'someAnimal is [Mammal "Mr. Biggles"]'`. That doesn't make sense to me because the `toString()` function is not being called anywhere.

Then to add even more confusion, if I change the `toString()` method to a method I make up such as `random()`:

```
function Mammal(name){ 
  this.name=name;
  this.random = function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  }
} 

var someAnimal = new Mammal('Mr. Biggles');
alert(someAnimal);
```

It completely ignores the `random` method (despite the fact that it is defined the same way was the `toString()` method was) and returns: `[object object]`

Another issue I'm having trouble understanding with inheritance is the value of `this`. For example, in the below example

```
function person(w,h){
  width.width = w;
  width.height = h;
}

function man(w,h,s) { 
  person.call(this, w, h); 
  this.sex = s;
}
```

`this` keyword is being sent to the person object clearly. However, does `this` refer to the subclass `man` or the superclass `person` when the person object receives it?

Thanks for clearing up any of the confusion I have with inheritance and object literals in JavaScript.

Comment: `toString` is a special method. It is implicitly called to get a string representation of the object when required as in inside the `alert` call. `random` is just a method that you created and has no special meaning or processing, hence nothing is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing with the `toString` method is caused because when you do a *string concatenation*, the object is converted *implicitly* to String (by the [`ToPrimitive`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.1) internal operation, using hint type "String").

That method invokes another internal operation, [`[[DefaultValue]](hint)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.2).

If the *hint type* is String, that operation explicitly gets the `toString` property and invokes it.

If your object doesn't explicitly define a `toString` method, the method will still be resolved higher in the prototype chain, `"[object Object]"` is the result of the [Object.prototype.toString](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.2.4.2) method.

For example:

```
var obj = {
  toString:function () {
    return "hello";
  }
};

alert(obj + ' world');
// will alert "hello world"
```

Now, about the `this` value:

The way you are constructing your objects is also known as *constructor chaining*, the `this` value will refer to a new object that inherits from the constructor's prototype that you called with the `new` operator.

The invocation of the other constructor with `call` will just make that all the property  assignments made to the `this` value inside the called function, are actually made on the new object from the first constructor, that doesn't really affect the prototype chain, for example:

```
function Person(w,h){
  this.width = w;
  this.height = h;
}

function Man(w,h,s) { 
  Person.call(this, w, h); // will just apply the width and height assignments
  this.sex = s;
}

var person = new Person(1,2);
person instanceof Person; // true
person instanceof Man; // false

var man = new Man(1,2,3);
person instanceof Person; // false
person instanceof Man; // true
```

**Edit:** To clarify more, when you invoke `Person.call(this, ...);` it just calls that function to make the assignments of properties of the `this` value (`this.width` and `this.height` on your example) on that function, to the object passed as the first argument of `call`, a simplified example:

```
function Test () {
  this.foo = 1;
  this.bar = 2;
  this.baz = 3;
}

var obj = { foo: 0 }; // a simple object
Test.call(obj);
// now obj looks like this: {foo: 1, bar: 2,baz: 3}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if "this" refers to man object or person object in above example, where man is inherited from person (man.prototype = new person(); man.prototype.constructor = man;)?

Comment: @John: `man` does not inherit from `Person.prototype`, when you invoke `Person.call(this, ...);` the assignments (`this.width = w;` and `this.height = h;`) are made to the `this` value inside the `Man` constructor, as I said, that doesn't affect the prototype chain (look the output of the `instanceof` operator I include).